# Smartface IS Secure Data-Fields don't work

Tags: database, encryption, smartface.io

I have created a local table and inserted some data. As long as I don't use `is secure` for fields all works fine. But when I use `is secure` for some fields I only get encrypted text for these fields. It seems that a decrypt function is missing. How to solve this?

For accessing the fields I use:

```
var field_value = Data.execute("select f3 from Testtable where rowid = 3;");
alert("Row 3:" + field_value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you should get encrypted values if you try this kind of sql execute statement, regardless from how many rows are selected as isSecure. 
I mean, if there is an isSecure field, it should always be seen as encrypted. Selecting some rows as inSecure or all of them as inSecure, shouldn't change anything.

The new release of Smartface App Studio is available right now. 
(http://account.smartface.io/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F )

I tested your case, it works fine with this new release.

By the way, if you want to reach the actual value in table, try the below code :

```
Data.myDataset.move(2);  //Lets reach the same row you wrote above with move
alert("Row 3 : " + Data.myDataset.f3);
```

You should write your dataset's name instead of myDataset.